# imagemagick: create a .png file which is just a solid rectangle

Tags: imagemagick

I want to create a .png file which is just a solid color.

This must be easy to do using ImageMagick but I can't figure out the problem:

```
C:\tmp>convert -size 8x16 -stroke black -fill black -draw "rectangle 0,0,8,16" black.png
Magick: missing an image filename `black.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageComm
and/3016.
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Obviously there can be more options, like borders and etc, but if you just want an image of width x height of a given hex color, it's pretty straight forward.

Here's all it takes to make an 100x100 image of a solid dark red:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:#990000 whatever.png
```

Comment: great, thanks! (btw, where's the docs for xc: and what does it stand for? I can't seem to find them via google)

Comment: It's a shortcut for color codes. You can put hex, rgb() or even a color name in there. I'm honestly not sure what it stands for though. More info: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php

Comment: You can also use rgba values `convert -size 100x100 xc:rgba\(255,0,0,0.4\) whatever.png`

Comment: This is what I love about unix tools. I was going to make a python program for this but then I remembered imagemagick. Nothing beats a bash one-liner

Comment: @luk3thomas does that make the `whatever.png` semi-transparent? I tried command (in graphicsmagick) and although the command succeeded, it created a solid red rectangle.

Comment: The `xc:#...` is a pseudo-image format; an alias for `canvas:#...` -- look at the "Pseudo-image Formats" section of http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: On Unix-like systems, hex colors and rgb(...) colors must be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 10):

Note that for rgb and rgba values, you need to escape the parentheses.  Building on @Mike Flynn and @luk3thomas (who correctly escapes the color code):

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:rgb\(0,255,0\) whatever.png
convert -size 100x100 xc:rgba\(0,255,0, 0.4\) whatever.png
```

Comment: Or quote : `convert -size 100x100 'xc:rgb(0,255,0)' whatever.png` or `convert -size 100x100 "xc:rgb(0,255,0)" whatever.png`  .

Answer (score 4):

In Mac

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:"#8a2be2" blue@2x.png
```