# Create blank image in Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

How to create a blank new image in Imagemagick via command line?

Using `-background` doesn't work:

```
$ convert -size 800x800 -background white x.png
convert: no images defined `x.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3257.
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771975/imagemagick-create-a-png-file-which-is-just-a-solid-rectangle

Answer (score 83):

## White background

```
convert -size 800x800 xc:white white.png
```

`xc:` used to mean "X Constant Image" but now is just a shorthand for `canvas:`. This means you can also use:

```
convert -size 800x800 canvas:white white.png
```

and because "white" is the default value if no color is provided, you can also use:

```
convert -size 800x800 xc: white.png
convert -size 800x800 canvas: white.png
```

## Transparent background

If by "blank" you mean "transparent", just use that word as the color:

```
convert -size 800x800 xc:transparent transparent.png
```

Answer made possible by [ImageMagick v6 Examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#solid) and [How to create a new image?](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=11747)

Comment: Actually, you can do it even more simply by specifying the size with the canvas... `convert xc:[800x800\!] white.png` or `convert xc:lime[800x800\!] lime.png`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell although from a human end user perspective, I would say that is less simple. I use `-size` all the time. Learning additionally `canvas:green` is the least amount of new information between these two options.

Comment: How cn I do it without having it assign the PNG a greyscale color profile?

Comment: minseong, I think @cjonasw have answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67427236/5623661) in this very page.

Answer (score 11):

You need to supply PNG24, PNG8 or PNG32 prefix if planning to use this canvas to layer colour images over. Without it, it creates a Grey colour space. I used 32, as I need "varying degrees of transparency for each pixel" (pixel art)

`convert -size 800x800 canvas:transparent PNG32:canvas.png`

For more about PNG types see [this link](https://blog.deepbluesky.com/news/-/the-difference-between-png24-and-png32-49/).