# PySimleGUI How can you put elements right next to each other, so that there is no space between them?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Is it is possible to put to elements (like `Button`s) right next to each other so that there is no space between them in `PySimleGUI`?

This is the code I have:

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def game_window():
    game_color = "#82a459"
    mana = 10
    potion = False

    sg.theme('Green')

    row1 = [ [sg.Text("z", font="Any 100", text_color=game_color)],
             [sg.Text("zzzzzzzzzzz", font="Any 100", text_color=game_color)],
             [sg.Text("zzzzzzzzzzz", font="Any 100", text_color=game_color)] ]


    row2 = [ [sg.pin(sg.Text(f"               {mana}                    ", key="_text_", font="Any 20"))],
             [sg.pin(sg.Button(key="_mana_", image_filename=r"mana256.png", border_width=0.1, button_color=game_color, mouseover_colors=game_color))] ]

    row3 = [ [sg.pin(sg.Text("zzzzzzz", font="Any 100", text_color=game_color))] ]

    row32 = [ [sg.pin(sg.Text("zzz", font="Any 10", text_color=game_color))] ]

    row4 = [ [sg.Button(image_filename=r"plank.png", border_width=0)] ]

    row5 = [ [sg.Button(image_filename=r"plank.png", border_width=0, pad=((15,0), (0,0))), sg.Button(image_filename=r"manapotionbuyz.png", key="_manabuy_", border_width=0.1, pad=((15, 0), (0, 0)))] ]

    layout = [ [sg.Frame(layout=row1, title="", border_width=0.1), sg.Frame(layout=row2, title="", border_width=0.1, ), sg.Frame(layout=row3, title="", border_width=0.1), sg.Frame(layout=row32, title="", border_width=0.1), sg.Frame(layout=row5, title="", border_width=0.1)] ]


    window = sg.Window('Wizard Clash', layout, element_padding=((0, 0), (0, 0)), margins=(0, 0, 0, 0), border_depth=0).finalize()
    window.Maximize()

    while True:
        event, values = window.read(timeout=1000)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':
            break
        if event == "_mana_":
            window["_mana_"].Update(image_filename=r"mana356.png")
            mana = mana + 1
            time.sleep(0.1)
            window["_text_"].Update(f"               {mana}                    ")
            window["_mana_"].Update(image_filename=r"mana256.png")
        if event == "Ok":
            potion = True
            mana = mana - 10
            window["_text_"].Update(f"               {mana}                    ")
        if potion == True:
            mana = mana + 2
        window["_text_"].Update(f"               {mana}                    ")

    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game_window()
```

As you can see I tried to put the buttons right next to each other, but there is still a space between them:

[image: screenshot showingpadding]

Answer (score 0):

Need to zero out margins & padding.

[image: plank]

Can [create blank images in imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504522/create-blank-image-in-imagemagick) as standins, but those are just guesses.

```
convert -size 10x100 xc:red plank.png
convert -size 32x32 xc:green manapotionbuyz.png
convert -size 32x32 xc:blue mana356.png
convert -size 32x32 xc:white mana256.png
```

[At the minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), **pixel sizes** for those would have been nice...

---

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
##  sudo apt install fonts-freefont-ttf
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def game_window():
    smallfontname = 'FreeSeriff'
    smallfontsize = 11
    smallfontstyle = 'italic'
    smallfont = smallfontname, smallfontsize, smallfontstyle

    mediumfontname = 'FreeSans'
    mediumfontsize = 22
    mediumfontstyle = 'normal'
    mediumfont = mediumfontname, mediumfontsize, mediumfontstyle

    largefontname = 'FreeMono'
    largefontsize = 33
    largefontstyle = 'bold'
    largefont = largefontname, largefontsize, largefontstyle

    game_color = '#82a459'
    text_color = '#224499'
    blank = '              '
    nada = ( 0, 0, 0, 0 )  
    mana = 10
    potion = False

    sg .theme( 'Green' )

    row1 = [ [ sg .Text( 'z', font = largefont, text_color = text_color ) ],
             [ sg .Text( 'zzzzzzzzzzz', font = largefont, text_color = text_color ) ],
             [ sg .Text( 'zzzzzzzzzzz', font = largefont, text_color = text_color ) ] ]

    row2 = [ [ sg .pin( sg .Text( f'{blank} {mana} {blank}',
                                  key = '_text_', font = mediumfont ) ) ],

             [ sg .pin( sg .Button( key = '_mana_',
                                    image_filename = 'mana256.png',
                                    border_width = 0.1,
                                    button_color = game_color,
                                    mouseover_colors = game_color ) ) ] ]

    row3 = [ [ sg .pin( sg .Text( 'zzzzzzz',
                                  font = largefont,
                                  text_color = text_color ) ) ] ]

    row4 = [ [ sg .pin( sg .Text( 'zzz',
                                   font = smallfont,
                                   text_color = text_color ) ) ] ]

    row5 = [ [ sg .Button( image_filename = 'mana356.png',
                           border_width = 0 ) ] ]

    row6 = [ [ sg .Button( image_filename = 'plank.png',
                           border_width = 0,
                           pad = nada ),

               sg .Button( image_filename = 'manapotionbuyz.png',
                           key = '_manabuy_',
                           border_width = 0,
                           pad = nada ) ] ]

    layout = [ [ sg .Frame( layout = row1,  title = '',  border_width = 0.1 ),
                 sg .Frame( layout = row2,  title = '',  border_width = 0.1 ),
                 sg .Frame( layout = row3,  title = '',  border_width = 0.1 ),
                 sg .Frame( layout = row4,  title = '',  border_width = 0.1 ),
                 sg .Frame( layout = row5,  title = '',  border_width = 0.1 ), 
                 sg .Frame( layout = row6,  title = '',  border_width = 0.1 ), ] ]

    window = sg .Window( 'Wizard Clash',
                         layout,
                         element_padding = nada,
                         margins = nada,
                         border_depth = 0 )
    window .finalize()
    ##  window .Maximize()

    while True:
        event, values = window .read( timeout = 250 )  ##  quarter-second between events
        if event == sg .WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':
            break

        if event == '_mana_':
            window[ '_mana_' ] .Update( image_filename = 'mana356.png' )
            mana = mana +1
            window[ '_text_' ] .Update( f'{blank} {mana} {blank}' )
            window[ '_mana_' ] .Update( image_filename = 'mana256.png' )

        if event == 'Ok':
            potion = True
            mana = mana -10
            window[ '_text_' ] .Update( f'{blank} {mana} {blank}' )

        if potion == True:
            mana = mana +2
        window[ '_text_' ] .Update( f'{blank} {mana} {blank}' )

    window .close( )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game_window( )
```