# ImageMagick error: zsh: no matches found: canvas: hex color in mac

Tags: macos, imagemagick

When creating a png image file which is just a solid rectangle in Mac, I have seen [imagemagick: create a .png file which is just a solid rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771975/imagemagick-create-a-png-file-which-is-just-a-solid-rectangle)

I use `convert -size 100x100 canvas:#ff9900 whatever.png`

issue is:

> zsh: no matches found: canvas:#ff9900

I use

```
convert -size 100x100 canvas:`#ff9900` whatever.png
```

, reading from http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php

Just a white image , not the color I set.

How to get through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are wrong. You used back-ticks, not quotes. In unix you can use single or double quotes for hex or rgb colors. I prefer to use double quotes as they can contain variables, if desired. Single quotes will not work with variables.

```
convert -size 100x100 canvas:'#ff9900' whatever.png

or

convert -size 100x100 canvas:"#ff9900" whatever.png

or

var="#ff9900"
convert -size 100x100 canvas:"$var" whatever.png
```

[image]

The above was using ImageMagick 6.9.10.23 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra. If using ImageMagick 7, then replace convert with magick.

P.S. I prefer to use a bash window rather than zsh.